# ASP.NET - Adding items to dropdownlist during construction

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

I have a web `user control` that holds three `dropdownlists`: One holds days, second holds months and the third one holds years. Days and months are static.But year items will change upon need to avoid entering wrong year. Let me first list here what I do in order, then i'll ask my question:

1. I have a private int yearSpan.
2. In private method PopulateYearList I say:

   ```
   int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
   int span = year - this.yearSpan;
   for (int i = span; i <= year; i++)
   {
       ddlYears.Items.Add(i.ToString());//Here I get NullReferenceException
   }
   ```
3. I've overriden the default constructor to receive `yearSpan` as an argument:

   ```
    public DatePicker(int yearSpan)
    {
       this.yearSpan = yearSpan;
       this.PopulateYearList();
    }
   ```

Now, as you might have guessed in my `PopulateYearList` method I get `NullReferenceException` because I try to add an item to `ddlYears` that has not been constructed yet. What would you suggest to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ether call the `PopulateYearList` in the `Page_Load` of your `usercontrol`. Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object objSrc, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.IsPostBack)
      PopulateYearList()
}
```

Or make the `PopulateYearList` `public` and call it on the `page` when you bind the `page` controls

Comment: Hmm, I think your second suggestion is just what I need. but it'd be very good if I could achieve this just by setting the date property. I wouldn't like to expose the internal structure of my class.

Comment: you'll understand why if you take a look at my comment to @Imran Rizvi's answer

Comment: Dear Arion, I did not -1 you. Don't know who did it. When I upvote, it first becomes -1 and then message box appears saying I can't upvote you unless you edit your answer. I think someone else downvoted. I hope you did not downvote my question because you think it was me. :))

Answer (score 1):

don't call this.PopulateYearList in constructor, rather call it on Load event of user control.

Also I prefer you to not use constructor of your user control rather use public property as it can maintain its state.

e.g. in Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UserControl1.TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Year;
}
```

In UserControl:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.IsPostBack) 
    {
      PopulateYearList() 
    }
}
```

As long as you don't make any change to that control from your parent page, any event after your controls are load , you can call this.PopulateYearList. I called it in PreRender event as if somebody changed the value from page it would be overriden by user control value at the end, thus I am sure my values are not tempered.

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: OK.This shoots away the NullReferenceException but there's a problem. The thing is when I load my page that contains this control I set its date property to DateTime.Now. In the setter of Date property I set the selected index to be the index of the current year. But as the Page_Load event of my DatePicker control raises only after my web form's Page_Load the items of my year list is emtpy.

Comment: @MikeJM modified the answer please check.